# Pegar ID de auto complete e passar para outro form auto complete como parametro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

Estou montando um cadastro onde seleciono o estado e um ajax busca as cidades o cliente seleciona a cidade mostro um form para ele digitar o nome do bairro onde uso o auto complete a minha dúvida é como pegar o id desse form/bairro que ele encontrou passo para outro form que deve usar o id do form/bairro para realizar novo auto complete e após isso enviar para um script que ira inserir tudo no bando de dados.

O que já tenho é o seguinte código do auto complete gostaria de ajuda para montar essa segunda parte

**busca_bairro.php**

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=$db", "$user", "$senha",
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bairro");
$dados->execute();
echo json_encode($dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="txtNome" name="txtNome" size="60"/>

<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Captura o retorno do retornaCliente.php
    $.getJSON('busca_bairro.php', function(data){
    var dados = [];
    // Armazena na array capturando somente o nome do EC
    $(data).each(function(key, value) {
        dados.push(value.nome);
    });
    // Chamo o Auto complete do JQuery ui setando o id do input, array com os dados e o mínimo de caracteres para disparar o AutoComplete
    $('#txtNome').autocomplete({ source: dados, minLength: 3});
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: voce ja tentou retonar o id nesse getJson e armazenar numa input hidden ho html?

Comment: Israel na verdade não sei como fazer isso será que poderi me ajudar com isso!

Answer (score 0):

Silva, como você não postou todo o seu formulário, não tem como sabermos se no mesmo arquivo html tem as tags php.

Se tiver, é só alterar a linha abaixo:

de:

```
$.getJSON('busca_bairro.php', function(data){
```

para:

```
$.getJSON('busca_bairro.php?id=<?=$id ?>', function(data){
```

Comment: Oi @prmas postei as páginas para que vc possa olha